# Check return type of ExecutableElement is subtype of Collection

Tags: java, java-annotations

I have an `ExecutableElement` representing a getter, an example is the one below.

```
public List<String> getStrings();
```

The only method that allows me to get the details of the return type is [ExecutableElement.getReturnType()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html#getReturnType()). It gives me back a [TypeMirror](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html).

I could not find anything that allows me to check if `TypeMirror` returned is a subtype of [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). What can I do to verify that? I am trying to generate the source code to call one of the methods in [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Comment: See [`Types#isSubType(TypeMirror,TypeMirror)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#isSubtype(javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror,javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror)).

Comment: @Slaw But how can I create a TypeMirror that represent Collection?

Comment: See [`Elements#getTypeElement(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getTypeElement(java.lang.CharSequence)) and [`Element#asType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.jdk.mapreduce.PreconditionsChecker

```
private boolean isIterbale(ExpressionTree expression) {
    TypeMirror tm = workingCopy.getTrees().getTypeMirror(TreePath.getPath(workingCopy.getCompilationUnit(), expression));
    if (!Utilities.isValidType(tm)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (tm.getKind() == TypeKind.ARRAY) {
        return false;
    } else {
        tm = workingCopy.getTypes().erasure(tm);
        TypeElement typeEl = workingCopy.getElements().getTypeElement("java.util.Collection");
        if (typeEl != null) {
            TypeMirror collection = typeEl.asType();
            collection = workingCopy.getTypes().erasure(collection);
            if (this.workingCopy.getTypes().isSubtype(tm, collection)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

[PreconditionsChecker](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=apache/incubator-netbeans/incubator-netbeans-master/java.hints/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/hints/jdk/mapreduce/PreconditionsChecker.java)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @PhuongHoang Take special notice regarding the use of [`Types#erasure(TypeMirror)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#erasure(javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror)).

Comment: @Slaw I did notice that erasure is used. I assume that this is to compare the raw type of the Collection. Is this what you are implying?

Comment: @PhuongHoang Yes. Otherwise you're testing the parameterized types.